# Finding similar instances in a high-dimensional dataset

Tags: similarity, measure

I am working on the task of predicting class labels for a cancer classification task. There are about 500 instances each with around 20000 features. To avoid overrating my classifier, I want to eliminate similar samples from the test data which resemble each other substantially. I have used the Manhattan similarity measure. Can someone comment on the applicability of the Manhattan measure for this purpose and/or suggest a better technique?

Thank you.